# overflow: hidden with position other than static doesnt work in chrome and safari, is this new? is this a bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, position, overflow

you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/TKb6M/1/ 
overflow hidden does not work with position fixed relative or absolute. is this new? because i think i remember using thins in chrome and safari before and it worked fine.

Comment: can you make little more clear.

Comment: @Anish yeah, if you set the parent elemnt to any position other than static, overflow: hidden doesnt work. it doesnt hide anything, and i tried this in FF4 and it works.

Comment: Tried this on Google Chrome Canary and it works correctly.

Comment: i have version 12.0.742.60, this is why im asking if its new so i know if this is a bug in the new version

Comment: Not a bug on: 13.0.771.0

Comment: put the border radius on the image.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question, because overflow:hidden works fine on your site using IE 9, FF 4, Safari 5, and Chrome 11.

Comment: Was this fixed ? My version is Chrome 18+ and I this is bug is valid for me. **EDIT**: This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera

Answer (score 0):

The results are only visible when the child element is larger than the parent element `overflow:hidden` is applied to (or when the child element's position falls partially outside of the boundaries of the parent element).
So in your example you're not seeing any difference because the child `img` and the parent `#he` both have the same width (70px).

Take a look at this update (the width of `#he` is changes to 30px): http://jsfiddle.net/TKb6M/10/

Comment: thanks but it was a bug only in that version, it should have cut the corners even with the same width and height, just like in all the other versions of chrome