# CSS Border radius not trimming image on Webkit

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, css

I'm having trouble figuring out why border-radius is gone from my #screen element when using chrome but not firefox or ie9?

I have all the different prefixes for each browser plus the standard border-radius:

www.cenquizqui.com

The upper content box that holds the pictures, called #screen

a copy paste of screen's css:

```
#screen {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;}
```

Is it because chrome does not handle the 'trimming' of the images properly? I thought it was only a problem when you had the actual  tags inside the rounded corner container, not when the img is called as background-image through css.

Regards
G.Campos

Comment: It does not work in Opera as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Webkit cannot handle border-radius cropping for children and grand-children+. It's just that bad. If you want border cropping, it has to be directly on the div the image is placed on without going any deeper down the hierarchy.

Comment: couldn't find any documentation regarding this bug or flaw - if anyone does, plz do tell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera

Answer (score 29):

Here's a workaround that will fix the current chrome bug:

```
.element-that-holds-pictures {
   perspective: 1px; /* any non-zero value will work */
}
```

This won't affect the display at all (unlike the `opacity:0.99` workaround - which is great workaround, too, by the way).

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer for Chrome Browser

Comment: Excellent! I used the `opacity:0.99;` workaround, since the `perspective:1px; ` although would fix it for Chrome/Opera, on animation would make disappear the container element for Firefox,

Answer (score 4):

There is a much simpler solution.

Just add `overflow:hidden` to the container that has the border-radius and holds the child elements. This prevents the children 'flowing' over the container.. Thus fixing the problem and showing the border-radius

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css to the child elements of the element with border-radius set:
`opacity:0.99;`
It solves the problem and doesn't change the opacity much.
This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to apply the border radius to the li element:

```
#slides li {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 300px;
width: 960px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That's going to give a very unappealing effect.

Comment: to me and you yes, only trying to assist with tracking down where Sotkra may look to make changes.

Comment: well yes, I can apply it to the li element, but then, as the slides get passed around, the 'corners' between slides wouldn't be seamless. Ultimately, the question here is, why does this happen on chrome but not ff or ie9?

Comment: From what I have read it appears to be a bug with chrome. Chris Coyier posted a link to a possible fix using JQuery: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/comment/45242#Comment_45242

Comment: The thing is, I dont have a div and an img inside it, I have a div with css background image. The solution normally presented for the people trying to get an img element inside a div is to apply the background img through css, and that is what im doing and it is still not working. This seems to be an overall flaw in chrome

Answer (score 0):

It very much does have a border radius:

[image]

(I just added a border with Chrome's dev toolbar.)

The border radius doesn't restrict its contents to within the resulting area—the space outside the corners are still occupiable by the element's contents.

My recommendation would be to overlay an image that had the corners cut out like that (and then use a map or whatever you feel comfortable with to still enable the left/right arrows).

Comment: Yes I know but...is this a chrome-only 'thing' because firefox seems to deal with it just fine. Hell, even the crappiest browser alive, ie9, handles it just fine. I wonder if this can be fixed with some sort of background clip property...

Comment: I was also wondering if the absolute positioning and z-index was ruining the clipping through border-radius. I removed both and the bug persists.

Comment: @Sotkra, Nope this also occurs in Safari and Opera. It seems that Firefox and IE are the ones that got it right. And you really should take another look at IE9/10 as their Javascript engine is by far the fastest and most responsive of all the browsers out there. IE has really cleaned up a ton of things and many of the big bugs I run into now are webkit issues.

Comment: I will, but im doubtful of anything microsoft builds =/