# rounded corners not inherited in webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm working on some sort of online indesign editor and i ran into the following problem. I'm placing divs on my page with a absolute position, and in that div i place a image, also with a absolute position, because i want to be able to drag the image around inside the div. I'm setting a border radius on the div but the image doesnt inherit that radius.

When i remove the position:absolute property on the div and on the image, the border radius gets accepted. But i need them to be positioned absolute.

You can find an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTVFR/)

As you can see, its doing it right on firefox but not on chrome and safari.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [demo on dablet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2922617)

`border-radius` is not inherited because of `position: absolute;` on `img`

**CSS:**

```
.pageelement {
    top:136.583px;
    left:-7.087px;
    height:288.142px;
    width:574.417px;
    position: absolute;
}

.pageelement img {
    width:785.923px;
    height:506.41px;
    left:-192.047px;
    top:-217.37px;
    position: absolute;
}

.pageelement,
.pageelement img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
            border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
}
```

PS. if you not [supporting Firefox 3.6](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius), you don't need `-moz-` prefix for `border-radius` anymore

Accordingly to this answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705249/css-border-radius-not-trimming-image-on-webkit) this behaviour is a bug:

> “Webkit cannot handle border-radius cropping for children and grand-children+. It's just that bad. If you want border cropping, it has to be directly on the div the image is placed on without going any deeper down the hierarchy.”

Only way to do it is to set image as a `background-image` of the element with `border-radius` and positioned it with `background-position`. via [Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/comment/45242#Comment_45242) from css-tricks discussion [thread](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/comment/45242)

Comment: Unfortunatly that didnt work, your not using the overflow hidden property, which i need to hide the parts of my image thet are outside of the div boundaries

Comment: Firstly, it works ([image](http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/7276/99f2cbac474e419f92c6c26.png)), Secondly, with `overflow: hidden;` you hide not only other parts of image but also rounded corners of it. I think you must to restructure you markup or reformulate your question.

Comment: I know what you mean, but strangely enough it works on firefox. So i gues it's more likely a chrome bug.

Comment: @vincent seems to me it is a webkit bug, I added some reference to my answer

Comment: I found another way in using `background-image` instead of using `image` tag

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can get your desired results through define the  **z-index** property in your class **.pageelement img**

I hope this will help you........

**HTML**

```
<div class="pageelement">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pageelement {
    top:136.583px;
    left:-7.087px;
    height: 288px;
    width: 593px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
    border:5px solid red;
}
.pageelement img {
    width:785.923px;
    height:506.41px;
    left:-192.047px;
    top:-217.37px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-10;

}
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/hTVFR/21/

Answer (score 0):

```
.pageelement {
    top:136.583px;
    left:-7.087px;
    height:288.142px;
    width:574.417px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.pageelement img {
    width:785.923px;
    height:506.41px;
    left:-192.047px;
    top:-217.37px;
    position: absolute;
}

.pageelement, .pageelement img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;        
}
```

​Unfortunately pageelement's position absolute is the reason for your troubles. Removing it should make this work!

http://jsfiddle.net/hTVFR/3/

Comment: You don't have overflow hidden which is as vincent stated, very important to his layout and .pageelement in my code is not absolute positioned!