# Openlayer map with rounded corners

Tags: openlayers

I integrate my openlayer map in a div with rounded corners. How can I get the map to have rounded corners? I have tried to apply border-radius to many divs in developer tools but the map refuses to get rounded corners.

Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me;

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yt2V8/)

```
#demoMap
{
    position: relative;        
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I think you probably just needed to add

```
overlfow: hidden;
```

to your CSS style, as the openlayers API just uses your div as a placeholder for it to insert many more elements.

**Update**

After reading the comment on Chrome I tried to get it working with Chrome but that does not seem to be possible
after reading [border-radius in Chrome bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705249/css-border-radius-not-trimming-image-on-webkit) and [CSS Border radius not trimming image on Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705249/css-border-radius-not-trimming-image-on-webkit) and using chromes dev tools to modify the element styles.

Comment: @Dampsquid: o.k., so it is a chrome bug. I am developing on chrome...  thanks a lot!