# Chrome: CSS Style is applied only when you go to Google Developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, openlayers, google-chrome-devtools, css

I was trying to apply rounded corners to an OpenLayers Maps, and found that it works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I found a related question [Openlayer map with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809926/openlayer-map-with-rounded-corners) which linked me to another question [CSS Border radius not trimming image on Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705249/css-border-radius-not-trimming-image-on-webkit), which explained that Google Chrome does not apply the rounded corners to grandchildren Images.

However, while testing if I could apply it directly to the children, I found a strange behavior.
If I open up chrome, and test the code out, it gives the wrong behavior(Images do not have the required rounded corner), but when I go to the Developer tools, and mouse hover over the elements tabs (which highlights the various divs in the page), the style is applied correctly, and I get the expected output with rounded corners.
You can test out the behavior on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K9qQ2/2/

The CSS code I have used is as follows:

```
#map{
    border: 6px solid #7AC49F;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    margin: 39px 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color:#eee;
}

div.olMapViewport {
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.olLayerDiv{
   border-radius: 25px; 
}
```

So is this a bug? Is there anyway to get Google Chrome to apply the style without going to the developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: block;` to the other divs.
  It seems to work in jsfiddle.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me in Google Chrome:26.0.1410.64 http://jsfiddle.net/K9qQ2/3/ Can you link to the jsfiddle where it works?

Comment: Hm, might have been a Chrome bug. See: https://pcbx.us/justinwiz/ahlt.png Some of the corners are not being rounded, but it certainly is being applied to the map.

Comment: ^ running Chrome for Mac 26.0.1410.65. Seems to be working sporadically when reloading the jsfiddle page as well