# Div border-radius flickers during css transform

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms, angular-material

I have a pretty simple web page I'm using as a playground for the Angular-Material package. It includes the following section:

[image: Section as it should look]

HTML:

```
<div class="margin-right community-photo">
  <img class="circle" src="images/cookiemonster-small.png">
</div>
<div flex layout="column" class="pad-vert">
  <span class="bold">C. Monster</span>
  <span>C is for Cookie, and Cookie is for me.</span>
  <span class="v-small-text">1 day ago</span>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
div.community-photo {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;

    img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 120px;
        left: -40%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
}
```

On other parts of the page I have some elements (a FAB, various Material Design buttons) that use CSS transforms to achieve effects like buttons sliding out, transparent bubbles and so forth.

[image]

```
<md-fab-speed-dial md-open="social.isOpen" md-direction="left" class="md-fling fixed-low-right" hide-sm show-md show-lg show-gt-lg>
    <md-fab-trigger>
        <md-button aria-label="Social Links" class="md-fab md-warn">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Like Us!</md-tooltip>
            <md-icon class="material-icons">&#xE8DC;</md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </md-fab-trigger>
    <md-fab-actions>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" href="">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Facebook</md-tooltip>
            <md-icon class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" href="">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Twitter</md-tooltip>
            <md-icon class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" href="">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Pinterest</md-tooltip>
            <md-icon class="fa fa-lg fa-pinterest"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" href="">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Instagram</md-tooltip>
            <md-icon class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" href="">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">YouTube</md-tooltip>
            <md-icon class="fa fa-lg fa-youtube"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-raised md-mini" href="">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">LinkedIn</md-tooltip>
            <md-icon class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </md-fab-actions>
</md-fab-speed-dial>
```

This element uses Javascript to apply a style tag with `opacity: 1; z-index: 6; transform: translateX(56px);` to the buttons when hidden, which it removes when they slide out. A `transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.55, 0.2)` CSS style provides the animation.

Strangely, when I use any of these elements, *from the time the CSS transform animation begins until the time it ends*, the `border-radius` on my div flickers off. It looks like this:

[image: Section as it should not look]

It only looks like that for 1 second, until the CSS transform finishes, but it's a flicker and it's making me sad. The actual CSS attribute doesn't get changed by Javascript or anything, it just flickers.

Just to be clear, it is definitely the `border-radius` attribute that is malfunctioning and nothing else. The picture itself is much bigger, so I know that the `overflow: hidden` is staying intact. It's not jumping to the right, so I know the absolute positioning is fine. But for some reason, the border-radius is flickering off momentarily.

Why might this be happening? I know that there are other ways to add a rounded picture to my site (CSS `background`, for example) but this way seems like the most intuitive and I'd like to keep it.

I have tried adding `!important` to the `border-radius` style and it doesn't change anything. However, if I remove the `position: absolute;` style from the `img` tag, it doesn't flicker. Therefore, it must be some interaction of `position: absolute;`, `border-radius` and `transform` which is causing the problem.

Comment: It would _probably_ be best to update your question showing relative sections of code, rather than trying to word around your code.

Comment: Good call. Incoming.

Comment: Would you mine setting up a simple codepen to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully someone out there has a better answer, but I've discovered a good workaround.

Change the style for the `img` tag from this:

```
position: absolute;
left: -40%;
```

To this:

```
margin-left: -40%;
```

(Removing the `position: absolute` style.)

This does the same thing and won't flicker.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug with using position and border-radius together. Its reported in answers on these questions as well, where when people removed the position property the border-radius worked fine. [StackOverflow Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248734/css3-border-radius-clipping-issues) and this one also- [StackOverflow Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855933/positionabsolute-within-border-radius-and-overflowhidden)

Comment: This may be a related bug, but it's impossible to say if it's the same, since my border-radius works great until the CSS transform happens. Thanks for the information all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

into the css.