# How to apply Border-radius with jScrollPane (jquery plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, css

I want to apply Border-radius Css property to a [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) div.

This is my desired solution (which as far as I know works well in modern browsers): http://jsfiddle.net/dF9ng/

However I want to apply this to a jScrollPane div.
This is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/SWtVC/

It seems to work correctly in Firefox. However in Chrome it doesn't work at all.

Is this a Chrome bug?
Is it working correctly in other browsers?
If it is a plugin bug, could someone provide me a fix or another possible solution?

Thanks in advance'

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: You can try for example for scrollbars: `.jspDrag {border-radius:14px}`

Comment: you might not be able to get a border on all four corners, only on the bottom right `.jspCorner{border-radius: 0 0 50px;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the article to position absolute, set its overflow to Hidden, however this won't work in Chrome/Safari, but there is a fix for it: [CSS masks](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/)

Your HTML markup remains as is, and here's your new CSS:

```
article{
    border:1px solid black;
    margin:30px;
    border-radius:50px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);

}
```

​

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dF9ng/2/)

I should also mention that, I found this by coming across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera).

Answer (score -2):

Check out my fiddle. I think this is what you wanted.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thewingser/SWtVC/13/)

Comment: This solution is not applying the jscrollPane correctly, the scrollbars are common ones not the plugin's.

Comment: Oh I see what your looking for. Check my updated JsFiddle it should work now

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. That solution doesn't work for Chrome.