# jQuery SWITCH inspired by apple will not constrain rounded corners

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

This FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/e7rGM/40/

Contains a switch inspired by apple. Due to the nature of the positioning of elements it will not constrain the rounded corners of inner elements once the animate function is animated. Is there a way to force it.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look one of the answers from this post, which suggests using `Webkit CSS Mask`.

[How to make CSS3 rounded corners hide overflow in Chrome/Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera)

This seems to fix your problem. Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7rGM/42/