# Webkit: Image covers rounded border

Tags: webkit, border, css

When using a rounded border on an image, webkit browsers hide the border behind the image

**CSS**

```
img {
    border: 10px solid #000;
    border-radius: 100%;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mbjei3b3re1r30y2do1_500.jpg" />
```

**Bug reproduced @ http://jsfiddle.net/zPpVm/**

This is probably related to [this Webkit bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5736503/681807), but I cannot find a suitable work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use a `box-shadow`:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px black;
```

**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zPpVm/1/)**

The main problem: It won't be calculated in the box-model

Answer (score 0):

As another workaround, you can wrap your image like this:

```
 <span class="img_container" >
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mbjei3b3re1r30y2do1_500.jpg" />
 </span>
```

Than style elements:

```
.img_container {
    border: 10px solid #000;
    border-radius: 100%; 
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img_container img {
    display: block;
}
```

All modern browsers except Opera will render it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as this is a CSS bug I don't like the idea of adding extra html as a solution