# Overflow: hidden not respected by border radius on chrome

Tags: html, overflow, css

I'm learning how to animate with CSS3 and wanted to make a simple "on hover show detail" image

I styled the container of the image to have a nice border radius, however the content as well as the overlay both clip over the edge of the radius even though overflow: hidden was applied

i realize there are some topics similar to this however most do not have a resolved answer.

any help?

my code : http://cdpn.io/rlnkz

Comment: Just a note that I can reproduce the issue running the latest stable Chrome, but the issue is not present in Chrome Canary. This indicates that it's likely a bug with Chrome.

Comment: This may be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with Chrome. You can work around it by duplicating your `border-radius` on `.image` and `.overlay`.

[Here's the updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdzLs).

**Edit**

[Here's another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera) that looks like the same issue.

Comment: I tried that already, but to get the radius the same is pretty much impossible without hacking it in. Do you think there is anyway of getting around this?