# CSS - hide scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I need to hide the vertical scrollbar on my website (without disable scrolling), in particular in mobile devices (touch scrolling).
I tried to achieve this by css, but i haven't good result, in particular with old browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make CSS3 rounded corners hide overflow in Chrome/Opera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera)

Comment: that is not my question. read the text before type please.

Comment: question without code except when your question is purely theoretical (and makes sense) is a complete NO-NO. JsFiddle - A definite YES

Comment: Use `overflow-y`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page

Comment: i don't read about mobile in your link. please explain

Comment: God, these two are a ray of sunshine, ay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer is

[Hiding the scrollbar on an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)

Disable it on desktop is the same on mobile.
Hope this help.