# Materialise wave affect doesn't work properly in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

I use Materialise and a try to activate `waves` style:

```
<a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" >
     <i class="mdi-content-add"></i>
</a>
```

Wave effect works properly in Chrome/Android but not in Safari/iOS.

For some reason when I click button, the wave distributes in rectangle and not in circle.

I tried to override style but it doesn't make sense:

```
.waves-ripple{
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

Here is [CODEPAN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbyqxr). Try to open in Chrome and after in Safari.

Any ideas how to fix it?

**[Edit]**

For now *light workaround* is to reduce wave size. This is what I did so far:

```
.my-btn-floating .waves-ripple {
    width: 8px !important;
    height: 8px !important;
}
```

[CODEPAN 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEMbjN)

**[EDIT 2]**

It also happens on Android S3/4 but not on Nexus4/5

Comment: you can check its default issue on plugin page  http://materializecss.com/waves.html

Comment: There is an issue posted on github related to this https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1019

Comment: You could use a `mask-image` as suggested [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera/10296258#10296258) but you will loose the ability to use box shadows in Safari and the rendering of edges is a little rough - [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPGdqg)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn please post your example as answer to let me vote up and accept because this way just works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1019) with Materialize caused by a [long standing Safari bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98538)

You could use `mask-image` as a workaround as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera/10296258#10296258)

```
a {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}
```

It may be useful to use a css hack to target only Safari as the quality of edge rendering seems to be reduced - [Safari hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25975282/746736).

Comment: Its not only Safari, Android S3/4 uses chromium and the same problem happens. Thanks again