# Why is my CSS animation breaking my overflow?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I've spent soo long trying to figure this out, and I cant see any  reason why this is causing this error. 
You can see, that the sun and land are visible outside of my scene div which has an overflow of hidden. 
Now if you go to the classes below and comment out that animation it will appear correctly.

```
.wing1 
.wing2
```

Why on earth is it acting this way? Is it because I have animation inside a div I am already animating?

```
.bird *is animated*
    .wing1 *is animated*
    .wing2 *is animated*
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/LukeD1uk/pen/LVWXmB

Any insight would be great.

Comment: Probably because of `border-radius: 50%;`.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, on latest FF its working ok, issue is on Chrome.

Comment: @Drops is right, seems like a browser issue. you may have to create an overlay to make your circle

Comment: All working fine here. Latest Firefox and latest Chrome, IE 11, Windows 8.1, no problems.

Comment: Why don't you try css clipping instead of `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: @LukeD1uk Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736503/how-to-make-css3-rounded-corners-hide-overflow-in-chrome-opera

Comment: @divy3993 Thanks that worked a treat, submitted that as an answer and I will approve it. :D

`-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); `

Comment: Its more like a duplicate question then, right? :)

Comment: @Drops well this is related to animations, so people will find this through other search results.

Comment: Np, just my 5 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS in your scene class

```
 position: absolute; /* this breaks the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); /* this fixes the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
```